# Call vue.js function in html to print value in p tag

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.8

**About**

I am using Vue.js Template with Laravel 5.8.

I am trying to call a vue.js function to show the value which will be returned by function in p tag

**Error Details**

Invalid Expression: Missing ) after the argument list. I want to show 1 in p tag. Am I missing anything?

Actually there is some complex data in the thread object and due to that I need to pass function to retrieve value and display it.

**Code**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="Thread in Threads">
            <p>{{ getName(Thread); }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return { 
                Threads: []
            }
        },
        methods: {           
            getName(Thread) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove a semicolon `;` in your template.

[Using JavaScript Expressions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      Threads: [1, 2, 3]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getName(Thread) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="Thread in Threads">
    <p>{{ getName(Thread) }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```